# BigQuery: Union two different tables which are based on federated Google Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have two different Google Spreadsheet:

One with 4 columns

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col5 | Col6 |
+------+------+------+------+
| ID1  | A    | B    | C    |
| ID2  | D    | E    | F    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

One with the 4 columns of the previous file, and 2 more columns

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID3  | G    | H    | J    | K    | L    |
| ID4  | M    | N    | O    | P    | Q    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I configured them as Federated source in Google BigQuery, now I need to create a view that will join data of both tables.

Both tables have `Col1` column, which contains an ID, this ID is unique across alla the tables, does not contain replicated data.

The resulting table I'm looking for is the following one:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID1  | A    | NULL | NULL | B    | C    |
| ID2  | D    | NULL | NULL | E    | F    |
| ID3  | G    | H    | J    | K    | L    |
| ID4  | M    | N    | O    | P    | Q    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

For the columns that the first file does not have, I'm expecting a `NULL` value.

I'm using standardSQL, here is a statement you can use to generate a sample data:

```
#standardsQL

WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT "A" as Col1, "B" as Col2, "C" AS Col3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "D" as Col1, "E" as Col2, "F" AS Col3
),

table2 AS (
  SELECT "G" as Col1, "H" as Col2, "J" AS Col3, "K" AS Col4, "L" AS Col5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "M" as Col1, "N" as Col2, "O" AS Col3, "P" AS Col4, "Q" AS Col5
)
```

A simple `UNION ALL` is not working because tables have different columns

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2

Error: Queries in UNION ALL have mismatched column count; query 1 has 3 columns, query 2 has 5 columns at [17:1]
```

And wildcard operator is not a suitable way because Federated sources does not support that

```
SELECT * FROM `table*`

Error: External tables cannot be queried through prefix
```

Of course this is a sample data, with only 3-5 columns, the real tables have 20-40 columns. So an example where I need to explicitly `SELECT` field by field it is not a considerable way.

Is there a working way to join this two tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a working way to join this two tables?

```sql
#standardsQL
SELECT *, NULL AS Col5, NULL AS Col6 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Yo can check this using your example

```sql
#standardsQL
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT "ID1" AS Col1, "A" AS Col2, "B" AS Col3, "C" AS Col4 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "ID2", "D", "E", "F"
),
table2 AS (
  SELECT "ID3" Col1, "G" AS Col2, "H" AS Col3, "J" AS Col4, "K" AS Col5, "L" AS Col6 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "ID4", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q" 
)
SELECT *, NULL AS Col5, NULL AS Col6 FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way which do not require to configure column names one by one, because in the real tables, the additional columns are up to 20//30, so maintaining that schema can be hard.
Is there any more automatic way? If the tables are "real" tables instead of external, can the wildcard be a suitable way?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I have too many columns to manually configure all the names. An outer union option in BQ would be really useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the rows through a UDF to handle the case where column names aren't aligned by position or there are different numbers of them between tables. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CoerceRow(json_row STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<Col1 STRING, Col2 STRING, Col3 STRING, Col4 STRING, Col5 STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
return JSON.parse(json_row);
""";

WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT "A" as Col5, "B" as Col3, "C" AS Col2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "D" as Col5, "E" as Col3, "F" AS Col2
),

table2 AS (
  SELECT "G" as Col1, "H" as Col2, "J" AS Col3, "K" AS Col4, "L" AS Col5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "M" as Col1, "N" as Col2, "O" AS Col3, "P" AS Col4, "Q" AS Col5
)
SELECT CoerceRow(json_row).*
FROM (
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t1) AS json_row
  FROM table1 AS t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t2) AS json_row
  FROM table2 AS t2
);
+------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| NULL | C    | B    | NULL | A    |
| NULL | F    | E    | NULL | D    |
| G    | H    | J    | K    | L    |
| M    | N    | O    | P    | Q    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Note that the `CoerceRow` function needs to declare the explicit row type that you want in the output. Outside of that, the columns in the tables being unioned are just matched by name.

Comment: I'm looking for a way which do not require to configure column names one by one, because in the real tables, the additional columns are up to 20//30, so maintaining that schema can be hard. Is there any more automatic way? If the tables are "real" tables instead of external, can the wildcard be a suitable way?

Comment: The wildcard approach would work for "real" tables. Given the constraints of your problem statement, though, spelling out the schema once is your best option. You could consider [filing a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) for a kind of "natural" unioning by column name, though.

Comment: Bravo!!! The definition of genius is taking the complex and making it simple (by Albert Einstein) Sometimes it is so obvious - but I am still learning a lot from Elliott's posts! Thank you!