# Conflict in UNION ALL on STRUCT fields

Tags: google-bigquery

This query works normally:

```
SELECT STRUCT<price STRUCT<previous FLOAT64, `current` FLOAT64, currency STRING>> (STRUCT(120.0 AS previous, 110.0 AS `current`, "BR")) UNION ALL
SELECT STRUCT<price STRUCT<previous FLOAT64, `current` FLOAT64, currency STRING>> (STRUCT(121.0 AS previous, 111.0, "BR"))
```

But if we change the order of the field definitions, like so (swapping  fields `currency` and `current`):

```
SELECT STRUCT<price STRUCT<previous FLOAT64, `current` FLOAT64, currency STRING>> (STRUCT(120.0 AS previous, 110.0 AS `current`, "BR")) UNION ALL
SELECT STRUCT<price STRUCT<previous FLOAT64, currency STRING, `current` FLOAT64>> (STRUCT(121.0 AS previous, "BR", 111.0))
```

We get the error:

> Column 1 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: STRUCT>, STRUCT> at [2:1]

Is this behavior expected?

The reason I'm asking is that we have 2 tables, one is fixed but the other is built every hour by using schema auto-detection on `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` files. As we can't set any order on the fields, sometimes the order they are defined changes and our code breaks.

As we don't have much control over the ordering the fields are defined I was wondering if BigQuery could have internally some sort of dynamic mapping on STRUCT fields for UNION operations (or if I did something wrong and there's a workaround for that)

Comment: If performance isn't a big concern, take a look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192791/6253347.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottBrossard! I already saw your answer to this question but just now realized it's the solution to the same problem! Definitely will be using it here!

Comment: @ElliottBrossard don't know if you can comment on this, just saw [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67859418) and as it seems, for BigQuery it's better to have struct defined as an orderly set of values. Still don't quite understand why this is the case as being like so makes auto-detection feature for instance potentially non-applicable. It just seems (in my limited knowledge ;) ) that having struct not ordered would fit better to the definition of a json like field (I'm also well aware this would be something of low priority to the team, I'm just mostly curious here)

Comment: It would make sense to have a JSON or document type that works in this way, and [there is an open feature request for it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69949409), but there has not been nearly as much interest an in other features, making it hard to prioritize :(

Comment: I see. Totally understand it, have been using BQ for quite a while and just now found this issue so it's probably something people won't find that easily. Still, given the speed at which BQ evolves it'd come as no surprise this support being in production soon :). Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this behavior expected?

Yes!

`STRUCT` is a container of **ordered** fields each with a type (required) and field name (optional).
See more at [Struct type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct-type)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, totally skipped the struct definition on the documentation. Always considered struct as an abstraction for the json fields, now I see I got it wrong :)

Comment: sure. check Elliott's answer he referenced in his comment - it is brilliant in my mind :o)

Comment: Agree, will be using it here :)